# 2006 Audi A4 2.0T, No passing power

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, audi, turbocharger

I have a 2006 Audi A4 2.0T Turbo Tiptronic Automatic that has no passing power.

When I step on the accelerator the car will shift down into a lower gear, rev about 3500 RPMs but will not shift up again until you let off the accelerator.  I have replaced the HPFP sensor and the Mass air flow sensor but neither has changed the performance.

When it revs to 3500 RPM, the speed is not increasing it just revs until you let off of the accelerator and then it will gradually get to the speed you want as long as you do not cause it to drop into the passing gear again.

I suspect that it is a sensor somewhere.

Any constructive feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it turbo or a V6? I don't know the answer either way but i know whoever does is gonna want to know more info. I assume its automatic and is it quattro?

Comment: Problems like this are either fuel or air. I'd check your fuel/air filters for a cheap starting point then work your way through to the exhaust. It is possible you have a clogged catalytic converter. Any check engine lights?

Comment: It sounds like you may have a problem with the Turbo.  Does the car have a boost guage?  If so, does it show boost under full throttle?  Also, did this start suddenly or has this been getting worse over time?

Comment: Are there any codes that pop up?

Comment: Following up on this oldish question: could you take your "additional information" comments and add them to the body of the question?  I'm having a little trouble following what the actual series of events is when this problem occurs.

Comment: Sounds like mine, too. http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3079/1626

Comment: The 2.0TFSI is a 4-cylinder engine. Afaik, tiptronic implies quattro (whereas multitronic implies front-wheel drive).

Answer (score 1):

If the engine is accelerating and the transmission is in gear, then the car should accelerate. If not, then you have a transmission problem. I'm not sure about Audi's, but what you describe sounds sort of like your torque converter (if you have one) is slipping under high load. If it is an "automatic manual" (or semi-automatic, depending on your preferred terminology), then your clutch is slipping.

Answer (score 1):

I had approximately the same problem and finally solved

Slow acceleration ( when you press on the gas pedal the rpm rise but acceleration is very slow )

The problem was a small crack in the pipe which connected from air filter to machine and this makes air leak. change the pipe and now big difference in acceleration. So, before changing any part first check all air pipes.

I got this solution after changed many pieces such as air filter and oil filter .... but It did not make any difference.

[image]